# Setting up an HKAnchoredObjectQuery so that I only receive updates since the last time I queried?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to set up an `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` that will only deliver results from the last time I made this query, but I can't get my head around the logic in setting up my HKQueryAnchor and how I persist it?  In [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkanchoredobjectquery) they do not show the initial declaration for the `HKQueryAnchor`.  Do I need to store locally the date of the last sample I downloaded and construct an anchor from that date?  This code below returns every sample in HealthKit.

```
func updateWorkouts(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        var anchor: HKQueryAnchor?

        let sampleType =  HKObjectType.workoutType()
        let workoutPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForWorkouts(with: .hockey)
        let sourcePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: HKSource.default()) //limit query to only this app
        let compound = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [workoutPredicate, sourcePredicate])

        let anchoredQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: sampleType, predicate: compound, anchor: anchor, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit) { [unowned self] query, newSamples, deletedSamples, newAnchor, error in

            self.handleNewWorkouts(newWorkoutsAsSamples: newSamples!, deleted: deletedSamples!)

            anchor = newAnchor

            completionHandler()
        }
        healthStore.execute(anchoredQuery)


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initializing an `HKAnchoredObjectQuery`, you are expected to either provide `nil` or an anchor object that you received from a query that you executed previously. You cannot directly construct an `HKQueryAnchor` yourself. To persist an anchor between application launches, you can encode it in persistent storage using `NSKeyedArchiver`. It is common to store the resulting encoded `NSData` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Thanks Allan, I set up using `UserDefaults` and is working well.